# My iPhone XS called someone today without my interaction

Tags: authentication, ios, phone, iphone, caller-id

Yesterday, I was sitting at the computer and noticed that the phone is making the "calling" sound (that usual beep). I **unlocked** the phone and did not see any activity like I would call someone, except the beep.

Today, it happened again. The same thing: heard the beep, unlocked my phone, and did not see like I would call anyone. However, a lady responded and said *Hi*. I asked her who she is, but she hang up the phone.

I do not see that phone call recorded in my phone logs, but I do know it happened.

As programmer, I know one cannot call anyone without user interaction on iOS. As well, I did not ask Siri to call someone, which I sometimes do (using Hey Siri).

I messaged the carrier to send me a log of the calls from their side, but I am still wondering what it is happening actually...

---

Related, but from my understanding different: [Someone called someone else with my phone number](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/220524/76797)

How can the phone running iOS, latest version, call someone this way — without any UI change on the screen (not even the green dot indicating the activated microphone, nor the telephone icon on the left top side)?

Comment: When it makes beep sound, does screen wake up automatically?

Comment: @defalt It does not. I unlocked it.